# Should editing a closed question bump it onto the front page?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This question was closed a bit ago and fell off the front page.

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5238/how-to-create-a-big-kahuna-reef-game-closed

There was an incorrect tag, so Ari Patrick corrected the tag. In doing so it brought the post back from the dead and placed the closed question on the front page where all it does is take up space for questions with actual activity on them.

I think it updating closed questions should not bump them onto the front page.

What do you all think?

**Should editing a closed question bump it onto the front page?**

*Edit: Should there be a checkbox to uncheck to make it not bump?*

*The person who edited it would have liked a choice to not bump it.*

http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/143556#143556

Comment: This really should be on meta stackoverflow, closing as off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think it should. Closing a question doesn't mean it's done for, usually it means this question needs to be repaired to be viable for the site. And if it falls off of the front page after being corrected it needs to be put in a position where people will notice it so it could be reopened.

If we want a question gone, we would lock and / or delete it.

Comment: I edited the question.